# How to send report created by Munin to email once per week

Tags: email, munin, report

I have a page with Munin reports and I want to send the email with graphs once per week on specific email. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Munin doesn't offer something like that out-of-box.

But, as it is only web pages, you just might script it :

1. `wget` everything to a local temporary directory (you might also use directly the local copy)
2. `tar.gz` it
3. send the `tar.gz` to the specific email